# cakephp paginate order ignored

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.3

i'm having trouble with order a paginate request.
I'm using a MySQL View table with two fields: id, date_ordered which is the earliest of two date field in the main table.
I'm using the exact same technique on an other App and all goes well. I can't figure out why the generated SQL doesn't show any ORDER BY clause.

Controller

```
public function admin($id=null) { 
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $this->DA->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'DAO.date_ordered LIKE '=>"$today%",
        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'DA_ordered', 
                'alias' => 'DAO', 
                'type' => 'INNER', 
                'foreignKey' => false, 
                'conditions'=> '`DAO`.`id` = `DA`.`id`'
            )
        ), 
        'order' => array('DAO.date_ordered' => 'desc'),
        'limit' => 1000
    );

    $this->set('req', $this->paginate());
}
```

I have no order field in the url, and the exact same code with same structure View table goes well in an other app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using:

```
'order' => 'DAO.date_ordered DESC'
```